# Exclude a specific dependency from springBoots `bootJar` gradle task

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, dependency-management, executable-jar

I need to exclude a specific dependency from springBoots `bootJar` gradle task (similar to the provided scope in maven).

I tried a custom configuration, but the `dependency-which-should-not-be-in-bootJar` is still included in the resulting jar.

```
configurations{
    provided
    implementation.extendsFrom provided
}

dependencies {
    // ...
    provided "dependency-which-should-not-be-in-bootJar"
}

jar {
    from configurations.compile - configurations.provided
    from configurations.runtime
}

bootJar {
    from configurations.compile - configurations.provided
    from configurations.runtime
    launchScript()
}
```

Comment: `bootJar` includes the runtime classpath by default. It inherits from `implementation` which you've configured to extend from `provided` As a result, the runtime classpath includes your provided dependency so it's include in the fat jar.

Comment: I also tried to change my `provided` to `providedRuntime` and let it extend from `runtime` after that I tried to configure the bootJar to override the runtime include with `from configurations.runtime - configurations.providedRuntime` which I thought should work but it doesn't. Can you point me to the right direction how to exclude a dependency properly from being packaged with the jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually use **compileOnly** for your dependency with gradle > 2.12

```
dependencies {
     // ...
     compileOnly "dependency-which-should-not-be-in-bootJar"
}
```

You will still have it for test + runtime, but not in the final built jar.

Comment: In my case I also had to add `testRuntime` but otherwise it worked perfectly thx.

Answer (score 5):

I also got an answer from [Andy Wilkinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384297/andy-wilkinson) in the spring boot gitter channel which works slightly different but manages to achieve similar.

```
configurations {
    custom
    runtime.extendsFrom custom
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    custom 'com.h2database:h2'
}

bootJar {
    exclude {
        configurations.custom.resolvedConfiguration.files.contains(it.file)
    }
}
```

Thank you Andy =)

Comment: It doesn't work for classpath folders: `resolvedConfiguration.files` still contains the folder `java.io.File` itself while `it.file` is a child of that folder

Comment: This worked for me: `configurations.custom.resolvedConfiguration.files.find { customEntry -> it.file.toPath().startsWith(customEntry.toPath()) } != null`