# Gradle Spring Boot Dependency: Include for bootRun / Exclude for bootJar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, javaagents

I have a JavaAgent JAR that needs to be:

- Included in `bootRun` (referenced in `bootRun_ManifestJar.jar` MANIFEST Class-Path)
- NOT Included in `bootJar` (the App.jar `BOOT-INF/lib` directory).

What I've tried thus far:

```
compileOnly "com.quartzdesk:quartzdesk-agent:3.6.0"
```

This is not including the JAR in either `bootRun` or `bootJar`

```
runtime "com.quartzdesk:quartzdesk-agent:3.6.0"
```

This is including the JAR in both  `bootRun` AND `bootJar` (surprised it is included in `bootJar`).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51130770/4982691) help?

Comment: @jumping_monkey I'll give this a try, thanks for your comment.

Comment: You are welcome, please update your findings(if any) so that it can help others. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

> surprised it is included in bootJar

`runtime` dependency means that it is not included in classpath in compile time, but it is still packaged in final `jar` into `libs` and loaded in classpath on application startup.

This is much useful for dependencies, which are not used in your application source codes like JDBC-drivers or Liquibase.

Comment: That is good information on `runtime`, it cleared up a lot for me.  Thanks.  I had always thought of `runtime` as "this is what is already there in a JakartaEE Server at runtime, but that seems to not be correct, especially in Spring Boot world.